# my sql workbench procedure failing to return result

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, workbench

I have created a movie database and I'm trying to write a procedure that returns all the films an actor played in.
The tables that I work with are:**actors**, **movies** and **movies_actors**, the tables are populated and the connection between them are working properly, because my queries are working fine.

The **actors** table:

```
| idA | nameA |
```

The **movies** table:

```
| idM | movieName|
```

The **movies_actor** table:

```
| idMA | idM | idA |
```

Now, the code for the procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS actor_movies;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE actor_movies(_actorName varchar(45))

BEGIN

    select
        actors.nameA,
        movies.movieName
    from
        actors 
    inner join movies_actor on
        actors.idA=movies_actor.idA
    inner join movies on
        movies_actor.idM=movies.idM
    where
        actors.nameA=_actorName;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This should return the movies that an specific actor played in, but it returns me an empty row.Anyone can tell me what am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

I have modified the code, but now it returns only the last movie that it finds.

My code is below:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS actor_movies;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE actor_movies(NameActor varchar(45))
BEGIN

set @id_actor = null;
select @id_actor := idA from actors where actors.nameA=NameActor;
select @id_FA := idF from movies_actors where idA = @id_actor;
select @movie_name := movieName from movies where idF = @id_FA;
if(@id_actor is not null) then
    select  @movie_name as result;
end if;


END
```

**This is the final version and it's working properly:**

```
drop procedure if exists movies_actor;

delimiter //

create procedure movies_actor(ActorName varchar(45))

begin

select 
    M.nameM as Film,

from 
    movies M,
    actors A,
    movies_actor MA
where
    A.nameA = ActorName and
    A.idA = MA.idA and
    MA.idM = M.idM;

end //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Have you tried this query outside the procedure? If it works outside the procedure, then cross check your syntax. Maybe something is not right?

Comment: the query is working fine if I set actors.nameA='freeman' for example...it's a syntax error but I don't where

Comment: put IN before the parameter (IN _actorName varchar(45))

Comment: already tried that too...maybe if the parameter that I give to the procedure it's **varchar** then actors.nameA=_actorName it's not valid

Comment: It is valid. However, actors.nameA and _actorName will both be of varchar(45) and calling the procedure will look like CALL actor_movies('Bruce'). Note the single quote in the parameter. Try removing all underscores.

Comment: still not working...I really don't understand what is happening...

Comment: Try out as single table query. Something simple. If it works, create a view of all actors and their movies. You can then use the procedure to query the view.

Comment: I've finally  managed to get it right, I will edit the post with the final version maybe it will be useful to others too. Thanks for the suggestions.